# Why would OpenCV's cascade classifier detection give way too large of an output?

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision

I am trying out the object classification in OpenCV (2.3) and the results are surprising.  As shown in my image below, I am trying to detect a full body and it is giving a region far too large for the detected region.

I am training the `CascadeClassifier` object with the provided haarcascade_fullbody.xml data.

I am detecting with this command: `cascade.detectMultiScale(temp, bodies, 1.1, 10);`

I am drawing the rectangle as such:

```
Point tl, br;
tl.x = bodies[0].x;
tl.y = bodies[0].y;
br.x = bodies[0].x + bodies[0].width;
br.y = bodies[0].x + bodies[0].height;

cv::rectangle(out, tl, br, cv::Scalar(255, 255, 255), 3);
```

Why is this not giving a good fit around the object?  Is there something I am missing here?  It seems to be consistently giving me too long of a region.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shouldn't `br.y = bodies[0].x + bodies[0].height;` be

`br.y = bodies[0].y + bodies[0].height;` ?

Just an idea...

Comment: Well, this is embarassing, haha!

Comment: Naaah, it can happen to the best of us :D